# MapKit: MKMapSnapshotter with custom tile source

Tags: ios, objective-c, mapkit, mkmapsnapshotter

How can I set a custom tile source (GCTileOverlay) of the MKMapSnapshotter? Is there any way or workaround to do so?

Comment: Did you find any solution for this problem?